# ErrorDlg with hyperlink

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In the installer I'm building, the user must have a minimum of .NET 4.6.1 If they don't, I cancel the installation.

```
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
<Condition Message="This requires .NET Framework 4.6.1 or higher.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED]]>
</Condition>
```

I want to add a hyperlink button to the .NET 4.6.1 download page from this error dialog. I can't figure out how to override the `ErrorDlg` and cannot simply add a new dialog because this page isn't part of the UI sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This resource](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-customized-dialog-boxes-wix) can give you a good idea of how to override `ErrorDlg` (search for `installer uses the Error dialog` on that page). Basically, here is the main quote:

> Create a new source file and call it ErrorDlg.wxs. This file should
>   set a property called ErrorDialog to the value you've set the Dialog
>   element's Id. In addition, the Dialog element should set the
>   ErrorDialog attribute to yes.

There are also example snippets down in the text. As soon as you manage to create a custom dialog like this and inject it into the sequence correctly, inserting a new control should be quite trivial.

Comment: see also http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Displaying-a-hyperlink-in-the-install-dialog-td7580689.html